# Echo two variables based on other two variables

Tags: php, variables

Im kind'of stuck on my project...can you help me?

What i'm trying to do is to echo in two different places either the variable `$open_text` and `$open_image` OR `$close_text` and `$close_image` based on current day and hour from the
first statement.

I've already tried with `switch -> case` but it didn't work. Another idea was to use variables variable but i dont quite know how to adapt it to my project. 
What i have is:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome'); // timezone 

$weekday = date(l); // today

// Set open and closing time for each day of the week
if ($weekday == "Tuesday" || $weekday == "Wednesday" || $weekday == "Thursday" || $weekday == "Friday" || $weekday == "Saturday") {
    $morning_open_from = "09:15";
    $morning_open_to = "12:30";
    $afternoon_open_from = "15:00";
    $afternoon_open_to = "19:30";
}
else {
    $morning_open_from = "00:00";
    $morning_open_to = "00:00";
    $afternoon_open_from = "00:00";
    $afternoon_open_to = "00:00";
}

// check if the current time is before or after opening hours
if (date("H:i") > $morning_open_from || date("H:i") < $morning_open_to && date("H:i") > $afternoon_open_from || date("H:i") < $afternoon_open_to ) {
    $open_text = "<span style='font-size:14px; color: green;'>We're open, call us!</span>";
    $open_image = "<span style='font-size:20px; color: #000; font-family: Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;'>0123.456789</span>";
}

// show the checkout button
else {
    $close_text = "<span style='font-size:14px; color: red;'>We're closed, contact us!</span>";
    $close_image = "<span style='font-size:20px; color: #000; font-family: Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;'>webmaster@webmaster.com</span>";
}
?>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please show where you want to echo these variables

Comment: Maybe i wasn't clear enough. I want to call and echo variables in two different divs inside html in pairs: either the variables $open_text and $open_image OR $close_text and $close_image, based on current day and hour from the first statement.

Comment: Ok then in that case the answer by Jim is what you want - dont use different variable names, just use $text and $image, and change the contents with your if/else check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever you want to echo you can either check to see if the variables are set before displaying them:

```
if(!empty($open_image)){
    echo $open_image
}
```

Or, since presumably $close_image or $open_image will be displayed in the same place you can just use the same variable:

```
if (date("H:i") > $morning_open_from || date("H:i") < $morning_open_to && date("H:i") > $afternoon_open_from || date("H:i") < $afternoon_open_to ) {
    $open_text = "<span style='font-size:14px; color: green;'>We're open, call us!</span>";
    $open_image = "<span style='font-size:20px; color: #000; font-family: Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;'>0123.456789</span>";
}else {
    $open_text = "<span style='font-size:14px; color: red;'>We're closed, contact us!</span>";
    $open_image = "<span style='font-size:20px; color: #000; font-family: Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;'>webmaster@webmaster.com</span>";
}
```

Then later you can just:

```
echo $open_text;
echo $open_image;
```

Comment: Thank you Jim, it's perfect.. i was complicating my life by using opening and closing variable four times :).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome'); // timezone 

    $weekday = date(l); // today        
    $openDays = array("Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
    $morning_open_from = "00:00";
    $morning_open_to = "00:00";
    $afternoon_open_from = "00:00";
    $afternoon_open_to = "00:00";

    // Set open and closing time for each day of the week        
    if (in_array($weekday, $openDays) ) {
        $morning_open_from = "09:15";
        $morning_open_to = "12:30";
        $afternoon_open_from = "15:00";
        $afternoon_open_to = "19:30";            
    } 

    // check if the current time is before or after opening hours
    if (( date("H:i") > $morning_open_from && date("H:i") < $morning_open_to )
            || 
            ( date("H:i") > $afternoon_open_from && date("H:i") < $afternoon_open_to )) {
        $open_text = "<span style='font-size:14px; color: green;'>We're open, call us!</span>";
        $open_image = "<span style='font-size:20px; color: #000; font-family: Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;'>0123.456789</span>";
    }

    // show the checkout button
    else {
        $close_text = "<span style='font-size:14px; color: red;'>We're closed, contact us!</span>";
        $close_image = "<span style='font-size:20px; color: #000; font-family: Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;'>webmaster@webmaster.com</span>";
    }
```